# List.map with multiple parameters in F#

Tags: list, f#, mapping

This is maybe easiest explained by an example.

Let's say I have this rather verbose function that raises an integer *x* to *nth* power.

```
let powInt = function
| x,n -> 
  let rec loop acc n =
   match n with
   | 0 -> acc
   | v -> loop (acc * x) (v-1)
  loop 1 n
```

If I now would like to raise each integer in a list of integers to the *nth* power, I thought the cool `List.map` function in **F#** would be the way to go:

```
let powIntList (xs: int list) = List.map powInt xs
```

However, in the last snippet the *n* power is lacking as an argument in the mapping - while the `int x` is implicitly extracted by the function `map`.

How do we add the *n* power argument in this example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make your function curried.

This is precisely the case for *currying*, which is a technique for formulating your functions in such a way that they take parameters "one by one", so to say. Mathematically, such function takes exactly one parameter, and returns another function that takes the second parameter. Something like this:

```
let curriedPowInt = fun n -> fun x -> powInt (x, n)
```

This way of defining functions is commonplace. In fact, it's so core to the very nature of ML-languages (of which F# is one) that there is a special syntax for it:

```
let curriedPowInt n x = powInt (x, n)
```

See how I just list my parameters in one line separating them with a space, like `n x =`? This is syntactic sugar for `fun n -> fun x ->`. Logically, it defines a function that takes parameters "one by one", not both at once as a tuple.

Now that you have such function, you can *partially apply* it - that is, give it just one parameter, not both:

```
let pow2 = curriedPowInt 2
```

This works, because - remember? - my function `curriedPowInt` takes `n` and returns another function that takes `x`. The type of `pow2` is now `int -> int`. It's a function that takes an `int` and raises it to the second power.

And of course, you can use this trick inline as well:

```
let powIntList (xs: int list) = List.map (curriedPowInt n) xs
```

Also, note how I changed the order of parameters. I put the `n` parameter first and the `x` parameter last. This is a general rule to make your functions more useful: put your "most important" parameter last, and "least important" first. Look at `List.map` itself for example: the list on which it operates is the last argument of the two.

Finally, instead of declaring `powInt` and then, separately, `curriedPowInt`, I recommend not declaring the former at all. Just make all your functions curried. Curried functions are way more useful. In fact, I have so rarely seen occasions where uncurried functions would be useful, I might as well have never seen any.

So, to summarize:

```
let powInt n x = 
  let rec loop acc n =
   match n with
   | 0 -> acc
   | v -> loop (acc * x) (v-1)
  loop 1 n

let powIntList (xs: int list) = List.map (powInt n) xs
```

Comment: Beautiful and informative answer, thank you very much! Will need to dive further into the wonders of this currying business.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: Great answer. Is `powIntList` missing `n` as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, it does. It doesn't have a parameter in the original question either, so I didn't want to add it in my answer to keep it minimal.

Comment: I wrote it inline:
`let powIntList xs n = List.map (fun x -> powInt x n) xs`